# How to keep RxJs observable from completing on error?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have an [angular reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) that makes a simple GET request. If for example, I should get some sort of HTTP error. The observable `todo$` has now completed I can no longer change my search options and click to retry searching. I've made a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-error-handling), in the demo I've added my subscription inside an initializer and if there is an error on the stream I catch it. After I catch it, I call the initializer again. This works but seems like the wrong way to handle errors.

I've set up the form so that I can cancel previous HTTP requests.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  todos;
  loading = false;
  useFakeURL = false;
  todoSub$: Subscription;
  todo$: BehaviorSubject < string > = new BehaviorSubject < string > ('');

  @ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput: ElementRef;

  constructor(private provider: ExampleService) {
    this.init();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.todoSub$.unsubscribe();
  }

  search() {
    const value = this.searchInput.nativeElement.value;
    this.todo$.next(value);
    this.useFakeURL = !this.useFakeURL;
  }

  private init(): void {
    this.todoSub$ = this.todo$.pipe(
        filter(val => !!val),
        tap(() => {
          this.loading = true;
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.provider.query(this.todo$.getValue(), this.useFakeURL)),
        catchError(error => {
          this.todo$.next('');
          this.init();
          return of([]);
        }),
      )
      .subscribe(
        todos => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.todos = todos;
        },
        err => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.todos = err;
        }
      );
  }
}

export class ExampleService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  query(todo, useFakeURL: boolean) {
    if (todo === 'all') {
      todo = '';
    }
    const url = useFakeURL ? 'poop' : `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${todo}`;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input #searchInput type="text" placeholder="Enter a number or enter 'all' to get all todos">
  <button (click)="search()">Get Todos</button>
</div>
<ul *ngIf="!loading && todos && todos.length">
  <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">
    <pre>
      {{todo | json}}
    </pre>
  </li>
</ul>
<pre *ngIf="!loading && todos && !todos.length">
  {{todos | json}}
</pre>
<div *ngIf="loading" class="loader">... LOADING</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked `retry`? See this article [Error handling in RxJS](https://medium.com/@kddsky/error-handling-in-rxjs-bac0f96a7def) for details

Comment: I have, not looking for the request to immediately retry, just want to be able to change the value of the input and search again.

Comment: Try putting `catchError` inside of the `switchMap`

Comment: @Kos that works! thanks, I assumed I was catching the error in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @kos I was catching the error in the wrong place. Since I switched to a new observable I should be catching the error inside `switchMap`. [UPDATED-DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fi8blx)

```js
search(term: Observable < string > ) {
  return term.pipe(
    filter(val => !!val),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(500),
    // attached catchError to the inner observable here.
    switchMap(term => this.searchTodo(term).pipe(catchError(() => {
      return of({
        error: 'no todo found'
      });
    }))),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular's Http requests are immutable. Observable returned from client execute actual call when you subscribe to it. As many times you subscribe as many requests will be made. That is so called "Cold Observable"

If you need to change request, you need a brand new observable from HttpClient.

Comment: Gotcha on the immutable part, but I have the behavior subject I'm subscribing to. That should never complete but it does, and when i click search again nothing happens. maybe cause of where I'm catching the error? if you comment out line 45 & 46 youll see that now clicking search does nothing.

Comment: You cannot comment out 46 as there mus be observable returned.

Comment: apologies meant 44 & 45.

Comment: But to be honest, I am not sure what is not working as you would want it to work. If i change input, new value is passed to service. As expected. What is wrong then?

Comment: Because I'm reinitializing the subscription with `this.init();`, if you comment out `       this.todo$.next(''); this.init();` it completes the observable