# Do something when all XHR requests finish - Angular 7

Tags: angular

How can I do something when all XHR Requests have finished in Angular 7?

```
 getGeneralPage(data, ServiceName: string, Type: string): Observable<Object> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        const lang = localStorage.getItem('language') === 'en' ? 1 : 2;
        headers.append('Content-Type',
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8');
        return this.http.get(
            this.apiURL + 'MOICDTacsoft/services/'
            + ServiceName + '/' + Type + '?WebsiteID=1&LanguageID='
            + lang + '&uniqueName=' + data, {
                headers: headers
            }).pipe(map(res => res)).finally(() => {
            this.loadingNotifier.next(false);
        });
    }


    getPollPage(categoryID: string, ServiceName: string, Type: string): Observable<Object> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        const lang = localStorage.getItem('language') === 'en' ? 1 : 2;
        headers.append('Content-Type',
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8');
        return this.http.get(
            this.apiURL + 'MOICDTacsoft/services/'
            + ServiceName + '/' + Type + '?WebsiteID=1&LanguageID='
            + lang + '&CategoryID=' + categoryID, {
                headers: headers
            }).pipe(map(res => res));
    }
```

Above, I have two requests and I'm using finally in the first one but the loading become false and the loader disappear before the second one finish, so how can I make sure that I can send a new value when all requests complete?

Comment: You could consider wrapping them in [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) or [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html) which you can subscribe() to do something when they complete or emit respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-onchanges-batches) of how you can make a single request and also a batch of requests. Hope it helps. Depending on how you are subscribed to the observables.

Here's another [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fi8blx?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts), where the observable plays the role of both the observable and the observer.

Here's a link to [SO-POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386182/how-to-keep-rxjs-observable-from-completing-on-error/55873042#55873042) to catch error's if you're going to use `forkJoin` which I also recommend.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  todo;
  todos;
  index = 1;

  constructor(private provider: ProviderService) {}

  getTodo() {
    this.provider.getTodo(this.index).subscribe(todo => this.todo = todo);
    this.index++;
  }

  getManyTodos() {
    const todos = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
    const todo$ = [];

    todos.forEach(todo => {
      const t$ = this.provider.getTodo(todo);
      todo$.push(t$);
    });

    forkJoin(todo$).subscribe(todos => {
      console.log(todos);
      this.todos = todos;
    });
  }
}



export class ProviderService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTodo(todo: number) {
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${todo}`;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```